# Is possible to set designer menu like in 4.3 version ( horizontal, top )?

Tags: phpmyadmin, designer

phpMyAdmin 4.4 brings new style designer menu.
Is possible to set designer menu like in 4.3 version ( horizontal, top )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not configurable at this time, however if you wish, you may [open a feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/) for it.